# Is it possible applicationWillTerminate not get called at termination?

Tags: ios, appdelegate

Saving when app normally terminated so to know it does not crashed. But in some reason this method is often not get called, I think, app is not crashing, get no crash log from our test users who turned on sharing the diagnostic data. But then why is `applicationWillTerminate` not called? Sleeping app can not interfere I think.

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"normallyTerminated"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

applicationWillTerminate will not be called if app is suspended when terminated. When terminating from app 'carousel' applicationWillTerminate will only get called if app was 'active' when carousel gets shown.

Comment: So if first suspended, then terminating, then it will not get called?

Comment: Yes, if you go from app to carousel and terminate, applicationWillTerminate will get called. if you are on the home screen or another app and you terminate, applicationWillTerminate will ordinarily not get called. The time window might be 3 minutes or so, but not sure.